# Fetch data, display local notification at same time everyday

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uilocalnotification

I would like to make an HTTP request once every morning, and then schedule a *UILocalNotification* which displays information from the request.

I do not want to use push notifications because of the server requirement.

I am currently testing iOS7's Background Fetch api:

`[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:60];
...
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  // Get data
  // Create UILocalNotification
}`

The problem is that the fetch has no guarantee. It could be executed too frequently, or worse -- too infrequently.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could 'version' your data received by the fetch and only create the local notification on version change (to handle too frequently) or elapsed time (to handle too infrequently)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm currently working on. But I'm worried about infrequently. If the background fetch doesn't happy 1x a day I have a problem. But even at 1x a day, if it isn't near to the time that I want to show the local notification, I'll have a data integrity issue.

Comment: @BigCheesy Ever get an answer?

Comment: No. I launched with this hacky solution and it's not working very well... the updates are spaced terribly. The background task won't be triggered for 2 days, then all of a sudden it'll get triggered 3 times in one hour.